# Has anyone noticed the problem with the phrase "head over heels?"

Tags: phrases

The phrase "head over heels" creates the image of someone cartwheeling because of terrific joy - usually it's used in referring to falling in love. However, the natural state of human beings is to be head over heels. That's how we are all the time. I read somewhere that the phrase originally was used as "heels over head," which makes sense, but it didn't have a good 'ring' to it, and gradually became the other way around. "Head over heels" rolls more easily off the tongue, in other words. Does anyone have any sources or information about this?

Comment: Human language is often ass over teakettle.

Comment: I’m sure it’s a back formation but you might think of it as being short for “head over, heels up.”

Comment: Dear The Photon - thank you! I think that's the probably most succinct answer.

Comment: I've often wondered whether _head over heels in love_ isn't an error for the earlier  [over head and ears](http://www.finedictionary.com/Over%20head%20and%20ears.html). I associate _head over heels_ with falling uncontrollably rather than cartwheeling with joy.